# Creating dummy variables using Scikit-Learn's feature_extraction

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My goal is I would like to create dummy variables from a column using SkLearn.

So I have data as follows:

```
INDICATOR MATCHUP 
1         [   "APPLE",   "GRAPE" ]
1         [   "APPLE",   "GRAPE" ]
0         [   "GRAPE",   "BANANA" ]
0         [   "PEAR",   "ORANGE" ]
1         [   "ORANGE",   "APPLE" ]
```

Dictionary of the data is as follows:

```
{'INDICATOR': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 'MATCHUP': ['[   "APPLE",   "GRAPE" ]',
  '[   "APPLE",   "GRAPE" ]',
  '[   "GRAPE",   "BANANA" ]',
  '[   "PEAR",   "ORANGE" ]',
  '[   "ORANGE",   "APPLE" ]']}
```

So I am looking to utilize Sklearn's text [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer). I need to use this package due to the nature of the pipeline I am building.

Final Outcome:

```
INDICATOR MATCHUP                    APPLE GRAPE BANANA PEAR ORANGE
1         [   "APPLE",   "GRAPE" ]   1     1     0      0    0 
1         [   "APPLE",   "GRAPE" ]   1     1     0      0    0
0         [   "GRAPE",   "BANANA" ]  0     1     1      0    0
0         [   "PEAR",   "ORANGE" ]   0     0     0      1    1
1         [   "ORANGE",   "APPLE" ]  1     0     0      0    1
```

I was able to succeed in the manipulation without Sklearn (see below) but I need to now use this Sklearn function to do so.

```
df.join(df['MATCHUP'].map(ast.literal_eval).explode().str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).sum())
```

I cannot use this since it will eventually go into a ColumnTransformer, so if we can use SciKit-Learn, I would appreciate it.

Comment: One comment on your given output: Using tfidf will not give you a matrix of ones and zeros, as the _idf_ part of tfidf means the counts are divided by the inverse document frequency. You can use a countvectorizer to get 1s and 0s, or you can use tfidf and get decimal values. Which are you actually looking for?

Comment: 1's and 0's, it would need to become a boolean variable in the end. @G.Anderson

Comment: As long as you're aware that that's a conscious choice you are making. An sklearn pipeline doesn't care whether the input is binary or decimal, and in fact it will be passed through as a sparse matrix anyway. I will post an answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a built-in text processor out of sklearn is much easier than the manual method you build yourself. It automatically takes care of the fact that your column of lists is actually a column of strings that look like lists by ignoring non-alphanumeric characters. I will also show the difference between the tfidfvecorizer that you say you must use, and the countvectorizer that would produce your given output.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer as cv
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer as tv

df=pd.DataFrame({'INDICATOR': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 'MATCHUP': ['[   "APPLE",   "GRAPE" ]',
  '[   "APPLE",   "GRAPE" ]',
  '[   "GRAPE",   "BANANA" ]',
  '[   "PEAR",   "ORANGE" ]',
  '[   "ORANGE",   "APPLE" ]']}).set_index('INDICATOR')

df

    MATCHUP
INDICATOR   
1   [ "APPLE", "GRAPE" ]
1   [ "APPLE", "GRAPE" ]
0   [ "GRAPE", "BANANA" ]
0   [ "PEAR", "ORANGE" ]
1   [ "ORANGE", "APPLE" ]
```

Here it is worth noting the distinction between the output you gave and what the normal output for one of these vectorizers is; namely a sparse matrix. Sklearn doesn't much care either way how you pass in the data, but I will show both the native output and the dataframe output.

###### TL;DR: Initialize a vectorizer, then use it to `.fit_transform(df['MATCHUP'])`

```
#first we apply the CountVectorizer to get the desired binary output
tf=cv()
#we will print the human-friendly version of the sparse matrix for comparison
print(tf.fit_transform(df['MATCHUP']))

  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 2)    1
  (1, 0)    1
  (1, 2)    1
  (2, 2)    1
  (2, 1)    1
  (3, 4)    1
  (3, 3)    1
  (4, 0)    1
  (4, 3)    1

#then we also convert to dense format and make a dataframe to show how it looks
count_df=pd.DataFrame(tf.fit_transform(df['MATCHUP']).todense(), columns=tf.get_feature_names())
print(count_df)

    apple   banana  grape   orange  pear
0   1       0       1       0       0
1   1       0       1       0       0
2   0       1       1       0       0
3   0       0       0       1       1
4   1       0       0       1       0
```

Then we can do the same with the tfidf to show the difference in output without the count vectors normalized with the idf (note the very similar output)

```
tf=tv()
print(tf.fit_transform(df['MATCHUP']))

  (0, 2)    0.7071067811865476
  (0, 0)    0.7071067811865476
  (1, 2)    0.7071067811865476
  (1, 0)    0.7071067811865476
  (2, 1)    0.830880748357988
  (2, 2)    0.5564505207186616
  (3, 3)    0.6279137616509933
  (3, 4)    0.7782829228046183
  (4, 3)    0.7694470729725092
  (4, 0)    0.6387105775654869

tfidf_df=pd.DataFrame(tf.fit_transform(df['MATCHUP']).todense(), columns=tf.get_feature_names())
print(tfidf_df)

    apple       banana      grape       orange      pear
0   0.707107    0.000000    0.707107    0.000000    0.000000
1   0.707107    0.000000    0.707107    0.000000    0.000000
2   0.000000    0.830881    0.556451    0.000000    0.000000
3   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.627914    0.778283
4   0.638711    0.000000    0.000000    0.769447    0.000000
```

Then, to complete the view that matches the requested output, we link the result back to the original (Note that this step is wholly unnecessary if you are using the transformers with a columntransformer/pipeline)

```
print(pd.concat([df.reset_index(),count_df], axis=1))

    INDICATOR   MATCHUP         apple   banana  grape   orange  pear
0   1       [ "APPLE", "GRAPE" ]    1       0   1       0       0
1   1       [ "APPLE", "GRAPE" ]    1       0   1       0       0
2   0       [ "GRAPE", "BANANA" ]   0       1   1       0       0
3   0       [ "PEAR", "ORANGE" ]    0       0   0       1       1
4   1       [ "ORANGE", "APPLE" ]   1       0   0       1       0

print(pd.concat([df.reset_index(),tfidf_df], axis=1))

    INDICATOR   MATCHUP         apple       banana      grape       orange      pear
0   1   [ "APPLE", "GRAPE" ]    0.707107    0.000000    0.707107    0.000000    0.000000
1   1   [ "APPLE", "GRAPE" ]    0.707107    0.000000    0.707107    0.000000    0.000000
2   0   [ "GRAPE", "BANANA" ]   0.000000    0.830881    0.556451    0.000000    0.000000
3   0   [ "PEAR", "ORANGE" ]    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.627914    0.778283
4   1   [ "ORANGE", "APPLE" ]   0.638711    0.000000    0.000000    0.769447    0.000000
```